# How to change the username/password and database runtime using HikariCP

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I have a multi tenant application that tries to connect to database per tenant and each database will have its own username/password. I want to achieve this using a single datasource by switching between the datasources and users.

I tried to set the username and password at runtime on getting the connection.

```java
Connection cnx = datasource.getConnection(username,password);
cnx.setCatalog(databaseName);
```

Unfortunately, the getconnection(username, password) is not implemented in HikariCP 3.1.0

Is there a way to achieve this. I know i can create the datasource per request and close it once the request is completed (not good solution). Also, I have more than 5000 tenants, so caching the datasource is not an option in my case.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

---Update---
I was able to set the user name/password at runtime, but not able to switch the database.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/).

Comment: It is again caching the datasources in memory. There is a limit on how many number of datasources you can cache depending on the number of open file descriptors.

Comment: Have you found a solution in the last year?